# How do I call a list from other classes?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, compiler-errors, bufferedreader

Okay so I am building a program that will sort grades and records of students. It is a command-line program and when run it will start by asking for user input. there are several commands such as exit(exits program), load [file name](loads a file name), student [student name] (loads student records), etc. the others are not important. Well basically what I am wondering and what I am stuck on is all those functions will be in separate classes and will be called when the user inputs a specific command, but if I put the "load" command in its own class, then how do I get it to share its information with the other classes? I know I have to use BufferReader to read in the files, but how would I go implementing my load class, or if there is a better way feel free to say so. here is my code so far. there isn't much on my other classes because I feel like I need to figure out how to read in and share the file with the other classes first.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class program7
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Grade Stats by ");
        System.out.print(">");
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {

            String input = scan.nextLine();

            if(input.equals("exit"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if(input.equals("help"))
            {
                System.out.println("exit                   - program closes.");
                System.out.println("load [filename]        - loads a class database specified in [filename].");
                System.out.println("students               - prints out a list of students from the class, along ");
                System.out.println("                         with total points, and final grades for each student.");
                System.out.println("assignments            - prints out a list of assignments from the file, along with points possible");
                System.out.println("student [student name] - Prints report for the student");
                System.out.print(">");
            }
            else if(input.contains("load"))
            {
                String[] split = input.split(" ");
                LoadStudents loadStudents = new LoadStudents(split[1]);
                loadStudents.getFromFile();
                System.out.print(">");
            }
            else if(input.equals("students"))
            {
                Students students = new Students();
                students.printer();

                System.out.print(">");
            }
            else if(input.equals("assignments"))
            {

                System.out.print(">");
            }
            else if(input.contains("student"))
            {
                String[] split = input.split(" ");
                Student student = new Student(split[1]);
                System.out.print(">");
            }
            else if(input.contains("assignment"))
            {

            }
            else if(input.equals("grades"))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("exit                   - program closes.");
                System.out.println("load [filename]        - loads a class database specified in [filename].");
                System.out.println("students               - prints out a list of students from the class, along ");
                System.out.println("                         with total points, and final grades for each student.");
                System.out.println("assignments            - prints out a list of assignments from the file, along with points possible");
                System.out.println("student [student name] - Prints report for the student");
                System.out.print(">");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

That is my main class, but here is my Load and Students class.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class LoadStudents
{
    public String inputFile;
    public List<Object> info = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public LoadStudents(String inputFile)
    {

        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }
    public List<Object> getFromFile()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            try
            {
                String line =  "";

                while(in.readLine() != null)
                {
                    line = in.readLine();
                    info.add(line);

                }


            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Exception, man");
            }
            finally
            {
            in.close();
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println("File wasnt found ");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception, man");
        }
        return info;
    }

}


import java.util.*;
public class Students
{
    public Students()
    {

    }
    public void printer()
    {
        List<Object> info = (new LoadStudents()).getFromFile();
        for (int x = 0; x<info.size(); x++)
        {
            System.out.println(info.get(x));
        }
    }

}
```

the Students class isnt finished but I am trying to figure out how to read the list from other classes. I have done research and have seen 3 similar problems, but they there is still something I'm missing because I keep getting the error

```
.\Students.java:11: error: constructor Load in class Load cannot be applied to g
iven types;
                List<Object> info = (new LoadStudents()).getFromFile();
                                     ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

I understand it wants input, but I want it to use the previous input the user gives it when he inputs the command "input [whateverfile]". 
Can anyone tell me how I can call that list my Load class produces to any other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. My suggestion is that your `Load` class should be a factory that actually creates a list of `Student` from the file, and not a list of strings.

Here are more suggestions:

- `Load` class could have all methods statics and it could be non-instantiable. The fields you have in this class are useless after the file is read, you can just pass them to the static method as parameters.
- `Load` is not a nice name for that class. `LoadStudents` is more meaningful, or even better `StudentFactory`.
- `Load` and `Student` probably don't need to be public, package-private are be enough. Same for all the methods in these classes. Always use the lowest visibility possible.
- `data()` is not a nice name for that method either. Something like `getStudents()`, or if you follow above advice, `getFromFile()`, is more meaningful.
- Always print/log the stacktrace of the exceptions, otherwise you won't even know what/where it happened.
- Instead of making the user type the whole commands, put a number on each option and let user select by number, that's faster to type and you avoid typo errors as well.
- Only import the classes you're actually working with and not the whole package, that will make the compilation faster (unless you're importing a lot of classes from that package, which is not the case here).

---

EDIT: since you still don't understand what I mean, here's an example:

```
class StudentFactory {

    private static List<Student> listCache = new ArrayList<>();

    static List<Student> getStudents(final String filePath) {
        if (listCache.isEmpty() {
            BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                String line;
                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Parse the line and create a Student instance from it, then add it to the list
                    listCache.add(student);
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Exception, man");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println("File wasnt found ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (in != null) in.close();
            }
        }
        return listCache;
    }

    private StudentFactory() {
        // Avoid instantiation
    }
}
```

Then you can just do

```
final List<Student> listOfStudents = StudentFactory.getStudents(filePath);
```

from anywhere in your code to get a list of students. `filePath` can be null if you already passed it previously.

Comment: Okay well that helps me with organization, but I need to be able to manipulate the list file. The file is a CSV file. its formatted to where the first line will start with "name," followed by assignment names, then next line will be the class name followed by points possible for the assignments on the first line, then any line after that will be formatted as student names followed by grades for each assignment. I need to be able to manipulate those lines in different classes in order to show it however the user asks. How would I access the List in my LoadStudent class in other classes?

Comment: I already answered your question. You return a `List<Student>` from your `getStudentsFromFile()` method instead of `List<String>`. You access it by calling `StudentFactory.getStudentsFromFile(filePath)`. There's no need instantiating `StudentFactory`.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If your question was about the error, you should have posted it in the first place instead.

Comment: Downvote explanation welcome so I can learn something.

Comment: No, I understood most of it. I am just trying to wrap my head around it. I am very new to java and I have a hard time synthesizing information, sometimes I need a different explanation, and the example helps a lot. Thank you for all your help